# How can i route this url to right routing map?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-routing

localhost/myfile.xml This url is requested and i am trying to convert it to Home controller's Config action . My solution is at below but exception says routing can't include '/' character . How i can do this ?

```
    routes.MapRoute("config",
        "/crossdomain.xml",
        new {controller="Home",action = "Config" });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove the leading slash; you don't need (and cannot have) it in a route.

Comment: I have tried it but empty action had no view and i thought problem was about routing. Thanks

Comment: Can i route this url to file directly ??

Comment: Yes, you can.  You can just create a normal file.